# How to reverse proxy dynamic image addresses and set up caching with nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

For example, if the real image address is `180.0.0.1?imgid=12345` , enter `domain.com/12345.jpg` in the browser and it will be successfully accessed and cache it on the browser.

How to configure nginx

Comment: Cached where?  On the proxy, or on the client?

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: @Brad cache on the  browser

Comment: For that, you just need a `Cache-Control` response header.

Comment: @Brad I don't know how to configure nginx to do the example I gave

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name domain.com;

  location / {
    expires max;
    try_files /$arg_imgid.jpg =404;
  }
}
```